# is there a server installable portal capture software?

Tags: server, dhcp, webserver, gateway, capture

I ask this as all i can find online is router installation packages. such as chillispot. I would rather install this directly onto my gateway server than on a router. 
i also tried using another installation instruction (part 2) from here : [Ubuntu Wi-fi Hotspot with Web Authentication](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498487/ubuntu-wi-fi-hotspot-with-web-authentication)

part of the instructions included ipv6 setup, my isp and my network does not support ipv6. (and to be honest, i do not want it to) i was just hoping someone had a simple package i could install and setup that does not require me to install and setup an entirely unneeded (nor wanted) protocol.

Comment: You can probably just skip the ipv6 bit if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found was to downgrade (reinstall) my system to 14.04 and install [GRASEhotspot](https://grasehotspot.org/documentation/installation/)

this worked the easiest for me.